# How to remove the blank space in unicode string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm new to python and trying to do some web scraping.
The string I got is : `u' Kathy  and Othon Prounis '`
The final output I want is `u'Kathy and Othon Prounis'`, where the extra spaces are removed.
I tried:

```
temp = re.split(' ',u' Kathy  and Othon Prounis ')
```

gives

```
[u'', u'Kathy', u'', u'and', u'Othon', u'Prounis', u'']
```

but I cannot do `temp.remove(u'')`on it.

Comment: If your goal is just to remove extra spaces, you can avoid arrays altogether and just do `result = re.sub(' +', ' ', s.strip())`, where `s` is the string to process.

Comment: `u' Kathy  and Othon Prounis '.strip().replace('  ', ' ')` gives you `u'Kathy and Othon Prounis'`

Comment: @LordSalforis That fails to give the correct output if multiple spaces are present in the middle of the string, since it's just replacing each individual space with another space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to ensure that a split does not happen at the start/end of the string. You can do that using regex lookarounds:

```
>>> re.split('(?<!^) +(?!$)',u' Kathy  and Othon Prounis ')
[' Kathy', 'and', 'Othon', 'Prounis ']
```

Alternatively, a major simplification to the regex would mean stripping your text *before* calling , so you should do that if it's an option.

```
>>> re.split(' +', ' Kathy  and Othon Prounis '.strip())
['Kathy', 'and', 'Othon', 'Prounis']
```

To that end, why not just do

```
>>> ' Kathy  and Othon Prounis '.split()
['Kathy', 'and', 'Othon', 'Prounis']
```

?